# some html does not works in outlook and word

Tags: html, markup

I have this HTML markup for an email template that works fine with firefox and IE 8 but does not works with outlook and ms word:

```
<p align="left" style="<style code >"> TEXT XXX <br/><span style="display: block; text-align: center;"><b> TEXT YYY </b></span></p>
```

basically what I want to do is display paragraph XXX and on the second line display YYY but the YYY should be centered and bold and should be just on next line ?

this works fine with firefox but since this is a email template and would be viewed in outlook... it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the span to 100% width?

so width:100%?

also, what does it look like in outlook currently?

Comment: it is completely left aligned